# How to replace all characters between two patterns in Bash?

Tags: bash, sed, echo, substitution, tr

I'm looking to replace all chars of a line of variable length starting with ( and ending with ) by = symbols.

Example:

```
line1 with some words
( + + +  +    +  +  )
line3 with some words
```

should be changed to:

```
line1 with some words
=====================
line3 with some words
```

It tried the following bash code, but it doesn't work, as it also changes white spaces in line1 und line3, too:

```
echo -e "line1 with some words\n( + + +  +    +  +  )\nline3 with some words"|tr ' (+)' '='
```

Result:

```
line1=with=some=words
=====================
line3=with=some=words
```

What do I need to fix in order to make it work?

Comment: can you confirm a) you'll only have a single pair of parens on a line and b) the line always starts with `(` and ends with `)`? or is it possible the line could have other characters before the `(` and/or after the `)`? could the line have multiple sets of the pattern `(...)` and if the answer is 'yes' ... could they be nested (eg, `(...(...)...)`?

Comment: Yes, I can confirm the input is exactly as shown. There are no other lines. Only line 2 needs to be replaced. @Cyrus already posted the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

If a row starts with `(` and ends with `)` then replace in this row all characters with `=`.

```
echo -e "line1 with some words\n( + + +  +    +  +  )\nline3 with some words" |\
sed '/^(.*)$/ s/./=/g'
```

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions:

- a set of parens may show up more than once in a line
- parens are not nested
- there may be other characters before the `(` and/or after the `)`

Sample input:

```
$ cat input.txt
line1 with some words
( + + +  +    +  +  )
line3 with some words
 xx (abc) yy (def) zz
```

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '
BEGIN { regex="[(][^)]*[)]" }
      { while (match($0,regex)) {
              x=""
              for (i=1;i<=RLENGTH;i++)
                  x=x "="
              gsub(regex,x)
        }
      }
1' input.txt
```

This generates:

```
line1 with some words
=====================
line3 with some words
 xx ===== yy ===== zz
```